# ¿Cómo añadir espacio vertical entre elemeentos en div? CSS

Tags: html, css

Dispongo de un **inventario de accesorios** en mi web.

Deseo agruparlos todos ellos en un div (grupal), y que a su vez contengan otro div (individual). Dentro de cada div (individual), insertar la imagen de cada accesorio junto con su nombre y un checkbox al lado. Preferiblemente he decidido -ordenarlos- de 3 en 3, otorgándoles a cada uno de ellos "30%" y que floten a la izquierda.

```
<div style='float:left; width:30%'>
```

**Ver imagen:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo correcto.
**Ahora la duda/pregunta:** ¿cómo puedo añadir un espacio vertical, creo que se deberá utilizar "padding" para separar los elementos de una fila y otra fila?

Añado el código:

```
<div class="mostrar_accesorios" id="mostrar_accesorios">
    <center>
    <h3><b>Accesorios</b></h3><br/>
    <?php 
        $objeto_accesorios = BD::obtenerAccesoriosPorCabana($_REQUEST["idcabana"]);
        $todos_accesorios = BD::todosAccesorios();
        foreach($todos_accesorios as $objeto){
            $existe = false;
            foreach($objeto_accesorios as $columna){
                //Si el accesorio global está en el accesorio de la cabaña, true.
                if($objeto->getIdaccesorio() == $columna->getIdaccesorio()){
                    $existe = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($existe){
                echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%'><img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' title='".$objeto->getDescripcion()."'/><br/><label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'><input type='checkbox' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]' checked>".$objeto->getDescripcion()."</label></div>";
            }else{
                echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%'><img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' title='".$objeto->getDescripcion()."'/><br/><label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'><input type='checkbox' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]'>".$objeto->getDescripcion()."</label></div>";
            }
            $existe = false;        
        }
    ?>
    <div style="clear:left"></div>
    </center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lo único que debes hacer es agregarle a los `div` un `margin-bottom`:

```
echo "<div style='float:left; width:30%; margin-bottom: 20px'><img src='imagenes/".$objeto->getDescripcion().".png' height='28px' width='34px' title='".$objeto->getDescripcion()."'/><br/><label for='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."'><input type='checkbox' value='".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' id='accesorio".$objeto->getIdaccesorio()."' name='accesorios[]'>".$objeto->getDescripcion()."</label></div>";
```

**Ejemplo funcional**

```css
.caja{
  float: left;
  width: calc(30% - 20px);
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.caja:nth-child(2n){
  background: chocolate;
}

.caja:nth-child(2n + 1){
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="caja"></div>
<div class="caja"></div>
<div class="caja"></div>
<div class="caja"></div>
<div class="caja"></div>
<div class="caja"></div>
```

Comment: Estas en todo, me quedo con tu propuesta.

Comment: Respuesta ejemplar de ambos.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso jajaja prácticamente hicimos lo mismo, saludos !

Answer (score 5):

```css
      #div1, #div2, #div3 {background-color: #f4f4f4; margin: 5px; width: 50px; height: 80px;}
        #div2 {margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; !important
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Divs with Margins</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eso quiza puedas hacerlo con el elemento 'margin' del css. Te dejo un ejemplo donde están separados por 5px tanto arriba como abajo, a excepción del div2 que solo posee margin a los lados.
Aunque veo que ya hay una respuesta mejor que la mía